# How to "merge" multiple pandas dataframes with the index as dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes: one:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('filename1.csv')
df1
     A     B
0    1     22
1    2     15
2    5     99
3    6     1
....
```

and two

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('filename1.csv')
df2
     A     B
0    1     6
1    3     52
2    4     15
3    5     62
...
```

I would like to merge these dataframes into a single dataframe, with column `A` as the index for this new dataframe.

The columns are filenames, the rows are the values for 'A'.

If values do not exist for these index, `NaN` then exists. The column names should be the filenames from the *csv above.

```
    filename1    filename2   
1   22           6
2   15           NaN
3   NaN          52
4   NaN          15
5   99           62
6   1            NaN
```

How does one do this? For two files, one could use `pandas.merge()`, but what is dozens of the orginal dataframes exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files = ['file1', 'file2']

def read(f):
    f = f + '.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=['A', 'B'])
    return df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A']).set_index('A').B

pd.concat([read(f) for f in files], axis=1, keys=files)
```

[image]

Comment: your solution is much more precise, i wasn't careful enough, when reading  OP's question...

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for this. When I try this for multiple files, I simply get multiple dataframes into one dataframe, with both column A and B include per each file. For multiple files, how do I explicitly index on column A?

Comment: There are some files where A is not the first column. Let's say I merge 20. Would it be easier to simply pre-process the files first and drop these (unnecessary) files such that A is the first?

Comment: @piRSquared Yes, the other columns could be dropped. This becomes clumsy for many files. I suppose you should define a function.

Comment: I get the error: "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: @ShanZhengYang you must have non-unique column A.  Try updated post.